# Arduino distributable program file

Tags: arduino

Similar to an .exe file, is there a way to make a 'distributable' of an Arduino program? Some sort of ready-to-upload file... I'd like to share the program but the code should be kept the most secret as possible, or at least make it hard to know.

Comment: sharing the code would be better as it allows different boards to be used from one file

Comment: Sure, but the sketch is only compatible with MEGA 2560, so in this case that's not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distribute the `.hex` binary file, and then let the users  upload the *binary* on the **Arduino** themselves.

The ordinary *Arduino IDE* already does that for you when you click on the button *verify & upload*, so you simply have to take the generated `.hex` file and give it away.

Or you can use [**Arduino Makefile**](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) to get your `.hex` *binaries* using any other development environment.

---

**Note:** even though the *source code* is not included nor displayed, it is possible to *reverse engineer* an `.hex` *binary* as much as it is possible to do it with an `.exe` *binary*.

Comment: .elf or .hex? https://www.kanda.com/blog/microcontrollers/avr-microcontrollers/find-arduino-hex-files-output-binaries/

Comment: Great. If I haven't explicitly used the EEPROM library, is it enough just the .hex file?